# how to find such matrices to compute $\sin A$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Could anyone tell me how to solve this one?

$A=\begin{bmatrix}5&-6&-6\\ -1&4&2\\3&-6&-4 \end{bmatrix}$, and given that $\sin A=B\times C\times E$, then find $B,C,E$.

I never solved such type of problem in past thanks for helping.

I see charpoly of $A$ is $\lambda^3-5\lambda^2+8\lambda-4=0$.

I also checked $P^{-1}AP=\text{diagonal}(2,2,1), P=\begin{bmatrix}2&2&1\\1&0&\frac{-1}{3}\\ 0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You could diagonalize $A$ and use the Taylor series of $\sin$. If  $A$ is not diagonalizable, the Jordan normal form can also be used.

Comment: I think the question probably meant to diagonalise $A$ and find its sine, so that if $A=PDP^{-1}$, then $\sin(A)=P\sin(D)P^{-1}$.

Comment: How to prove that statement @user1551

Comment: As the answer below says, $\sin A$ is defined using a power series. That's why you can pull out $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and evaluate the matrix sine at $D$ only.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the matrix is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), i.e. $A = P^{-1} \Lambda P$, where $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ - all the eigenvalues of A on the main diagonal and all other entries are $0$'s. And $P$ is the eigenvectors of $A$ stacked in columns.

It is straight-forward to show $$A^n = P^{-1}\Lambda^n P.$$

Then just define functions of matrix as the Taylor expansion, e.g.
$$\sin A = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}A^{2k+1}$$

and substitute $A^k$ in.